# some apps are not using the proxy I provided... I think

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

New linux user here
I've been using http injector to share my vpn trough hotspot for my laptop (running ubuntu 22.04) which uses a proxy setup for my wifi connection. I've done all that and I'm using it on most of websites and apps but some (such as steam and appimage files) won't go trough the proxy. any ideas?